# How to load (add to a panel) by terminal (CLI) a Cinnamon applet newly added to /usr/share/cinnamon/applets?

Tags: bash, linux-mint, terminal, cinnamon, dconf

I've found out to edit Cinnamon panel I can use `dconf`:

```
dconf read /org/cinnamon/enabled-applets
['panel1:left:0:menu@cinnamon.org:0', 'panel1:left:1:show-desktop@cinnamon.org:1', 'panel1:left:2:grouped-window-list@cinnamon.org:2', 'panel1:right:2:systray@cinnamon.org:3', 'panel1:right:3:xapp-status@cinnamon.org:4', 'panel1:right:4:notifications@cinnamon.org:5', 'panel1:right:5:printers@cinnamon.org:6', 'panel1:right:6:removable-drives@cinnamon.org:7', 'panel1:right:7:keyboard@cinnamon.org:8', 'panel1:right:8:favorites@cinnamon.org:9', 'panel1:right:9:network@cinnamon.org:10', 'panel1:right:10:sound@cinnamon.org:11', 'panel1:right:11:power@cinnamon.org:12', 'panel1:right:12:calendar@cinnamon.org:13', 'panel1:right:1:temperature@fevimu:14']
```

I have been able to add and remove applets by `dconf write`, but only for those that were enabled already as seen in GUI (panel right-click->applets) and/or after adding once by GUI.

How to add/load applet that was just added to `/usr/share/cinnamon/applets` via terminal commands?

Answer (score 0):

On Github I got a suggestion to use schemes and overrides and wrote a script:

```
# edit panel
# editing /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.cinnamon.gschema.xml or 10_cinnamon.gschema.override
schema_override_file=/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_cinnamon.gschema.override
if [ ! -e "$schema_override_file" ]; then
    echo '[org.cinnamon]' | sudo tee "$schema_override_file" > /dev/null
fi

changed_panel=`grep 'panel1:right:' /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.cinnamon.gschema.xml | perl -pe 's/ *.{1,2}default.//g' | perl -pe 's/(right:)([0-9]+)/$1.($2+2)/eg' | perl -pe "s/]/, 'panel1:right:0:mem-monitor-text\@datanom.net', 'panel1:right:1:temperature\@fevimu']/"`

echo "enabled-applets=$changed_panel" | sudo tee --append "$schema_override_file" > /dev/null
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
```